# What does the MySQL USING statement do in conjunction with DELETE?

Tags: mysql

What does the MySQL `USING` statement do and is there any docs on this?

MySQL USING statement example

```
DELETE FROM l, s 
USING l
INNER JOIN s ON s.skill_id = l.id
WHERE s.user_id = 3
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In a DELETE, you can list tables after the USING clause, from which rows do not get deleted (i.e., to only be part of the WHERE clause). For example:

```
DELETE FROM t1, t2 
  USING t1 
    INNER JOIN t2 
    INNER JOIN t3
  WHERE t1.id=t2.id AND 
        t2.id=t3.id;
```

Your particular example can be achieved without USING in this fashion:

```
DELETE l,s 
FROM l 
  INNER JOIN s 
    ON s.skill_id = l.id 
WHERE s.user_id = 3
```

Comment: In your first example, rows from 11 as well as t2 will be deleted. This seems to contradict your explanation ("you can list tables after the USING clause, from which rows do **not** get deleted").

Comment: @kloplop You're correct that rows from t1 and t2 are deleted; as those are in the DELETE/before the USING.  However, the query also makes use of t3, from which rows wouldn't be deleted.  i.e. USING enables you to include additional tables in your query to those from which you wish to delete from.

Answer (score 0):

The USING clause is used to set column existence criteria for two tables in a JOIN.

So, if I have a statement such as:

```
SELECT * from a
JOIN b
USING (c1,c2)
...
```

what will happen is that the MySQL engine will first verify that columns `c1` and `c2` exist in both tables, and then compare the values of those columns to perform the join on the two tables.

See MySQL documentation for [JOIN Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html).

Comment: That is another use of the USING statement, but not the one he is referring to in his question.

Answer (score 0):

Search for `USING` in the MySQL documentation for [DELETE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html). It is just an alternative syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax for `USING` statement -

```
DELETE [LOW_PRIORITY] [QUICK] [IGNORE]
    FROM tbl_name[.*] [, tbl_name[.*]] ...
    USING table_references
    [WHERE where_condition]
```

for detailed info visit [USING](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html)

Comment: No, the use of `USING` in the question is part of the multi-table DELETE syntax.